# How can i use myst_parser with sphynx in readthedocs?

Tags: python, markdown, python-sphinx, read-the-docs, myst

I can build the docs completely fine on my computer and open the HTML result and it looks great, but when I push to GitHub and read-the-docs tried to build it- I get the following error:

`root file /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/cry-vs-py/checkouts/latest/docs/index.rst not found`

my index file has the `.md` extension instead of `.rst`. how can I tell read-the-docs to use that? again

my [my GitHub repo](https://github.com/AW1534/cry-vs.py), [my readthedocs page](https://cry-vs-py.readthedocs.io)

I need to be able to use .md instead of .rst because I just really don't understand restructured text. thank you.

Comment: What's stopping you from renaming your index file so it's what is expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the value for [`source_suffix`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-source_suffix) in your `conf.py` to include Markdown files.

```py
source_suffix = [
    ".md",
]
```

Then install a source parser extension, such as [MyST](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sphinx/intro.html). See the parser's documentation for installation and configuration details.

Comment: I have already tried doing that, but it doesn't fix the issue

Comment: Please provide a link to your build's log file on RTD. Usually it indicates the problem. I suspect that you have not specified requirements that your project requires to build the docs, whereas you have installed them locally.